# How to mention path of action method in external JS function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have written a jquery functions in external JS file and included that file where ever i required.

In jquery function i called action method from my controller. Now my problem is i'm not able to locate that action method path from the external JS. It is throwing error that is method not found like that.

Now **how i can write the action path name in the external JS which will work from any where.**

I tried following for mentioning/calling action method -

```
1. url: "/Employee/AutocompleteSuggestions" 


2. url: "AutocompleteSuggestions"

3. @Html.Raw(Url.Action("AutocompleteSuggestions", "Employee", new { @term = "Term", @moduleName="ModuleName"}))
```

3rd is not working because of razor syntax.

How to resolve this problem ?

I used the JS like below -

```
       $.ajax({
                url: "AutocompleteSuggestions",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                data:
                    JSON.stringify({
                        term: request.term,
                        moduleName: "Employee"
                    }),
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.FullName, value: item.Id }
                    }
                    ))
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
            })
```

Comment: i added part of code from jquery function from external JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue you have here is that you will *probably* need to use a global; which could be vulnerable to script attacks.  See my original answer for the most naive implementation.

I think this is probably pretty safe - but there are much better Javascript gurus out there who might have a better answer.

In your layout/master you can just output a script block like this (I'm using Razor):

```
<script>
  function myActionMethods(){
    this.MyActionMethod = function(){
      return '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
    };
  }
</script>
```

And then include your script *after* that, using something like this:

```
var methods = new myActionMethods();
$.get(methods.MyActionMethod());
```

When you need to use that URI in your script (just demonstrating here with a jQuery Get).

***In response to your comment on @David's answer***

Sure; you can use Razor to output the JS:  Just write a controller action that fires a Razor view which returns javascript (although you'll have to do a little mucking around with the response types) but if you do this you lose all caching/compression benefits on that script and then you have to write that all back in again.

Comment: thanks. Then give me one favor for which one is better solution for above mentioned issue ?

Comment: I think I kinda suggested which one I favour, no?  Losing caching and compression etc unless you write it back in is not favourable.

My solution is simply introduced to your whole site with a master and partial view being called from that, and then you simply assume the `myActionMethods` object is defined.

Comment: and one more thing is that i added multiple function like i mentioned in above code in a single JS file and which will required paths of action methods from different controls action methods. Then how i use above mentioned solution in my case ?

Comment: Well, `Url.Action` takes all route values - so that's not a problem is it?  Just make sure the name you give them on the object are different (which they should be anyway)

Comment: i'll try ur suggestion and if any problem then let u know.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the path to the action somewhere in your _Layout.cshtml, for instance in the body tag like this

```
<body data-jsactionurl="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")">
```

Then you can get this in your JS file like this (jQuery):

```
var action = $("body").attr('data-jsactionurl');
```

Or even like this:

```
var action = $('body').data('jsactionurl')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible to write it in JS file itself ? I know this solution. But i want it in external file itself.

Comment: There are other ways, but I think this is the nicest I know of. If you want it in the same file as your javascript you could put all of your script in a partialview instead of a .js file.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use like this it's below

```
url: "@Url.Content("~/City/State")"
```

In that url first your controller Name and second your action Name

in my project i am using like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/City/State")",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { countryId: countryID },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#stateID").empty();
                $("#stateID").append("<option value='0'>--Select State--</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
                    alert(optiondata.StateName);
                    $("#stateID").append("<option value='" + optiondata.ID + "'>" + optiondata.StateName + "</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Faild To Retrieve states.');
            }

        });
```

i think this will hepl you...

Comment: but in my project it's working are you using virtual directory ?

Comment: i used jquery in external JS file so that's why it is not executing that Razor syntax.